# Qt Virtual Keyboard [PyQt 5.8]- Style not being found, unable to resize virtual keyboard

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I have been trying to work with Qt Virtual Keyboard and it has been going pretty good, until...

---

**The problem is:**

1. Environment variables being set. (kinda check)
2. QT_VIRTUALKEYBOARD_STYLE(not found). I've already created my own style, from another stackoverflow post, seems pretty good, but it's not being found.

> WARNING: Cannot find style
>   ".../INTERACT/interact-ii/tools/en_GB/customkb.qml" -
>   fallback: "default"

**Some attempts:**

1. Have put the customkeyboard.qml alone file inside my own project and set the variable to its path.
2. Have put the whole folder "en_GB" from the default Qt folder inside my project with my modification.
3. Have also set the variable with the original path from the Qt folder with my style.
4. Downloaded Qt 5.8/5.7/5.6 and did the same for all the qtvirtualkeyboard.
5. After seen the above error (fallback: "default") I tried to add my qml items to the default.qml from the qt folder. [.../Qt/5.8/Src/qtvirtualkeyboard/src/virtualkeyboard/content/styles/default]
6. Have opened the qtvirtualkeyboard.so file with QTCreator and build all after changing my qml files also to see if it would change something and nothing changed.

**None of them seems to modify my keyboard size and location.**

---

### Here are the files that matter with a small example.

**1 - Small example using the keyboard.**

```
import os
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QProcessEnvironment
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget

os.environ["QT5DIR"] = "/home/epson/Qt/5.8/gcc_64"
os.environ["QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH"] = "/home/epson/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/plugins/platforms"
os.environ["QT_PLUGIN_PATH"] = "/home/epson/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/plugins"
os.environ["QML_IMPORT_PATH"] = "/home/epson/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/qml"
os.environ["QML2_IMPORT_PATH"] = "/home/epson/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/qml"

os.environ["QT_VIRTUALKEYBOARD_LAYOUT_PATH"] = "/home/epson/INTERACT/interact-ii/tools/en_GB/customkb.qml"
os.environ["QT_VIRTUALKEYBOARD_STYLE"] = "/home/epson/Qt/5.8/Src/qtvirtualkeyboard/src/virtualkeyboard/content/styles"
os.environ["QT_IM_MODULE"] = "qtvirtualkeyboard"

for i in QProcessEnvironment.systemEnvironment().keys():
    print(i)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.line_edit = None


        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.line_edit = QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit2 = QLineEdit()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_widget = QWidget()
        self.main_widget.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.line_edit)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.line_edit2)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**2 - My customkeyboard.qml**

```
/****************************************************************************
**
** Copyright (C) 2016 The Qt Company Ltd.
** Contact: https://www.qt.io/licensing/
**
** This file is part of the Qt Virtual Keyboard module of the Qt Toolkit.
**
** $QT_BEGIN_LICENSE:GPL$
** Commercial License Usage
** Licensees holding valid commercial Qt licenses may use this file in
** accordance with the commercial license agreement provided with the
** Software or, alternatively, in accordance with the terms contained in
** a written agreement between you and The Qt Company. For licensing terms
** and conditions see https://www.qt.io/terms-conditions. For further
** information use the contact form at https://www.qt.io/contact-us.
**
** GNU General Public License Usage
** Alternatively, this file may be used under the terms of the GNU
** General Public License version 3 or (at your option) any later version
** approved by the KDE Free Qt Foundation. The licenses are as published by
** the Free Software Foundation and appearing in the file LICENSE.GPL3
** included in the packaging of this file. Please review the following
** information to ensure the GNU General Public License requirements will
** be met: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html.
**
** $QT_END_LICENSE$
**
****************************************************************************/

import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard 2.1
import "content"

Item {
    width: 1280
    height: 720

    Item {
        id: appContainer
        width: Screen.width < Screen.height ? parent.height : parent.width
        height: Screen.width < Screen.height ? parent.width : parent.height
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        rotation: Screen.width < Screen.height ? 90 : 0
        Basic {
            id: virtualKeyboard
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.bottom: inputPanel.top
        }

        /*  Handwriting input panel for full screen handwriting input.

            This component is an optional add-on for the InputPanel component, that
            is, its use does not affect the operation of the InputPanel component,
            but it also can not be used as a standalone component.

            The handwriting input panel is positioned to cover the entire area of
            application. The panel itself is transparent, but once it is active the
            user can draw handwriting on it.
        */
        HandwritingInputPanel {
            z: 79
            id: handwritingInputPanel
            anchors.fill: parent
            inputPanel: inputPanel
            Rectangle {
                z: -1
                anchors.fill: parent
                color: "black"
                opacity: 0.10
            }
        }

        /*  Container area for the handwriting mode button.

            Handwriting mode button can be moved freely within the container area.
            In this example, a single click changes the handwriting mode and a
            double-click changes the availability of the full screen handwriting input.
        */
        Item {
            z: 89
            visible: handwritingInputPanel.enabled && Qt.inputMethod.visible
            anchors { left: parent.left; top: parent.top; right: parent.right; bottom: inputPanel.top; }
            HandwritingModeButton {
                id: handwritingModeButton
                anchors.top: parent.top
                anchors.right: parent.right
                anchors.margins: 10
                floating: true
                flipable: true
                width: 76
                height: width
                state: handwritingInputPanel.state
                onClicked: handwritingInputPanel.active = !handwritingInputPanel.active
                onDoubleClicked: handwritingInputPanel.available = !handwritingInputPanel.available
            }
        }

        /*  Keyboard input panel.

            The keyboard is anchored to the bottom of the application.
        */
        InputPanel {
            id: keyboard;
            y: screenHeight; // position the top of the keyboard to the bottom of the screen/display

            anchors.left: parent.left;
            anchors.right: parent.right;

            states: State {
                name: "visible";
                when: keyboard.active;
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: keyboard;
                    // position the top of the keyboard to the bottom of the text input field
                    y: textInput.height;
                }
            }
            transitions: Transition {
                from: ""; // default initial state
                to: "visible";
                reversible: true; // toggle visibility with reversible: true;
                ParallelAnimation {
                    NumberAnimation {
                        properties: "y";
                        duration: 250;
                        easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### QUESTION:

Am I doing things wrongly about setting STYLE and LAYOUT variables? Which one of them both should I really been setting up, is it the STYLE or the LAYOUT variable that would change the size and location of my keyboard? Where should I really put the qml file? What am I doing wrong? Can't see what is the problem!!

*Obs: Even following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43128979/6801746) couldn't make it work. Did everything exactly the same but seems something is missing or I'm misunderstanding something.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are confusing layouts for styles which is creating several problems for you.

### Layouts

1. The .qml files in the en_GB directory are what Qt uses for the keyboard *layout*.
2. To include your custom layouts, you must point the QT_VIRTUALKEYBOARD_LAYOUT_PATH var to the directory you created for your custom layouts (e.g. QT_VIRTUALKEYBOARD_LAYOUT_PATH=/path/to/custom/keyboard-layout/mycustomlayout). Then, to add a custom layout for British English, you would create a en_GB directory in /path/to/custom/keyboard-layout/mycustomlayout. In your en_GB directory, you should have, at the very least, main.qml.
3. You have named your file customkeyboard.qml. In order for Qt to correctly locate, load, and process your custom layout, you must follow the file naming convention of the default layouts (i.e. main.qml, handwriting.qml, symbols.qml), as referenced [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/technical-guide.html#layout-types).

### Styles

For custom styles, you must put your custom style directory in $$[QT_INSTALL_QML]/QtQuick/VirtualKeyboard/Styles, as referenced [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/technical-guide.html#keyboard-styles). Obviously, your custom style.qml file goes in your custom style directory.

Hopefully that helps clarify some things for you.

Comment: Ohh, I think I got the difference between then now. Just to be sure then, if I want to move my keyboard to a different location and change its size I should work with a custom style, am I right? The rest I'll figure it out. Already thanks a lot for the response. Will try what you suggested and get back ")

Comment: Hey Matt, I've get the en_GB layout, put into my project, set the QT_VIRTUALKEYBOARD_LAYOUT_PATH to my en_GB path inside my project. I got lost from here, where should I put my layout (with the location and size)? Should I edit the main.qml from the en_GB, or create my own file.qml. The path should be from the whole folder or just my file.qml with the layout I want. Got a bit lost from here.

Comment: I completely understand the confusion. The semantics in Qt lend themselves to ambiguity.

Comment: To clarify, `QT_VIRTUALKEYBOARD_LAYOUT_PATH` should be set to en_GB's containing folder. To confirm that you’ve got everything set correctly for the layout, I would just swap the first two keys in `main.qml` (e.g. the ‘W’ in place of the ‘Q’) to verify that Qt is using the layout you intend to manipulate.

Define the location, size, etc. in `style.qml`. That file should be placed in `$$[QT_INSTALL_QML]/QtQuick/VirtualKeyboard/Styles/YourCustomStyleNameGoesHere/style.qml` with `QT_VIRTUALKEYBOARD_STYLE` set to `$$[QT_INSTALL_QML]/QtQuick/VirtualKeyboard/Styles/YourCustomStyleNameGoesHere`

Comment: Hi there again Matt, sorry for be bothering you that much, I finally got my style working and for some reason my layout doesn't go to the one I define with QT_VIRTUALKEYBOARD_LAYOUT_PATH. But anyways, since I want just change size and location and it's in style, I'm struggling a lot to do that, I've been messing around with  
keyboardDesignWidth
keyboardDesignHeight
keyboardRelativetopMargin
...
and none of them seems to change. My layout gets crazy, only its inner keys change size and location, not the kb size/location itself. Read that should be somewhere inside InputPanel, any advice?

Comment: I've read that I should just set "width" and "y" variables in InputPanel and the height would adjust itself, about the location I'd just have to set its anchor parent, .... But I'm still kinda lost on that, where I should put that, but when I try to put it in Style it just breaks and there is no attribute of that type. I'm really 'noob' with qml and I'm about to explode trying to make that work for almost a week. Would you have any direction about those things I just said?