# QtVirtualKeyboard - Change layout not working

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qtvirtualkeyboard

Following the QT-API I got to make the custom style working putting it inside the correct folder and make the required modification from [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/technical-guide.html#keyboard-styles).
Now I have tried to use my own custom [LAYOUT](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/technical-guide.html#layout-types) making the following modifications:

1. I took the en_GB folder from /Qt/5.8/Src/qtvirtualkeyboard/src/virtualkeyboard/content/layouts/en_GB
2. Copied to my own path and renamed it to customkblayout.
3. Modified its main.qml file from 
   `...
   Key { key: Qt.Key_Q text: "q" } 
   ...`

   to

   `... 
   Key { key: Qt.Key_Q text: "w" }
   ...`
   to see if it changed when I open the keyboard.
4. Set the variable environment `os.environ["QT_VIRTUALKEYBOARD_LAYOUT_PATH"] = ".../customkblayout"`

These are all the variable environment I changed:

```
os.environ["QT5DIR"] = ".../Qt/5.8/gcc_64"
os.environ["QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH"] = ".../Qt/5.8/gcc_64/plugins/platforms"
os.environ["QT_PLUGIN_PATH"] = ".../Qt/5.8/gcc_64/plugins"
os.environ["QML_IMPORT_PATH"] = ".../Qt/5.8/gcc_64/qml"
os.environ["QML2_IMPORT_PATH"] = ".../Qt/5.8/gcc_64/qml"
os.environ["QT_VIRTUALKEYBOARD_LAYOUT_PATH"] = ".../customkblayout"
os.environ["QT_VIRTUALKEYBOARD_STYLE"] = "custom"

os.environ["QT_IM_MODULE"] = "qtvirtualkeyboard"
```

**Problem:** When I open the qtvirtualkeyboard it seems that the variable environment is not working at all. It keeps the default layout that I don't even know where it's coming from. I even tried to modify the main.qml inside its own folder in .../en_GB and recompile it through QtCreator and nothing changes too.

**Question:** Is there any other variable I'm missing out? What am I doing wrong? Can't figure out how to change it and can't find anywhere how to do it more then I have already done.

Continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44166147/qt-virtual-keyboard-pyqt-5-8-style-not-being-found-unable-to-resize-virtual) question, where I tried to use style and already got this part, now only missing the Layout part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, you are referencing **Qt 5.8**, but the **QT_VIRTUALKEYBOARD_LAYOUT_PATH** environment variable was added in **Qt 5.9**.

Please see the commit here tagged Qt 5.9: https://github.com/qt/qtvirtualkeyboard/commit/d51fd422289d8077ef23dd3b5f8d2df6827787b6

Hope that helps!

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer? Put in it the pieces of code needed for the OP to understand the solution (instead of linking to a git)

Comment: Thanks for the answer abDevAB, soon I'll have a look at it and see how it goes. Any light is very welcome :D